# Duration of single qubit gate in IBM

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, ibm-q-experience

how can we calculate the duration of single qubit gate using Qiskit in IBM? In other words if I have to insert a delay in the place of the single qubit gate, how would I know how much delay in nanosecond needs to be provided?

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
idle_identity = QuantumCircuit(1,'q')
idle_identity.delay(300 * 16, qreg_q[0])
```

I can see that a delay of 300x16 is assigned to qubit 0 of a quantum device. Likewise is there any way that I can precisely extract the gate duration of single qubit gate (e.g. sx, rz gates) so that I can replace 300*16 with the corresponding duration.

Answer (score 2):

It's available from backend properties's `gate_length`.

API Doc: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.models.BackendProperties.gate_length.html#qiskit.providers.models.BackendProperties.gate_length

For example, the `id` gate usually has a gate length of 30 ns.

Answer (score 1):

1. Measure a qubit without a gate in super position.
2. Measure a qubit with a gate in super position.
3. Substract (2) - (1) to get the time.

I suggest to do this with 1000 Shots each to have a more precise result.

[image: without gate you want to measure]
[image: with a gate]